# Embedded ActionScript in SWF

Tags: php, ruby, actionscript-3, flash

I have .swf files coming from about 50 graphic designers from all over the country, most of which have created a slideshow or video and then converted it to a .swf file.

I then send these files to another company that serves them through a proprietary piece of software that looks for an FSCommand (ActionScript 3) to signify the end of the video.

I want to create something simple that I can import these .swf files they are receiving from their designers that will add the FSCommand to the last frame of the video and then re-export the file as .swf again as I often don't have a source .fla file to work with.

My idea was to create a simple web app that will do this for them, my problem is I don't know enough about the .swf format (or have been able to find the right information online as of yet) on how to do this.

Hoping someone here knows either how to do the above in either PHP or Ruby, if there is already an application that can do this or if you have a better idea on how to complete this task. I'm not asking for someone to write anything for me, just a nudge in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing an old thread.

For others, I wasn't able to solve this. We ended up contacting the designers and having them add the command on their end.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the way you want to do it but I will give it a shot because it is a neat way of embedding an SWF into another SWF using `ByteArray`. You will get access to the timeline and the function addFrameScript that allows you to add a callback function on a frame in the SWF. When you compile your new SWF it will embed the original SWF and add a script to the last frame calling the function `lastFrameHandler`.

The important part is this:

```
_animation.addFrameScript(_animation.totalFrames - 1, lastFrameHandler);
```

>

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    import mx.core.ByteArrayAsset;

    [SWF( frameRate="30", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF", width="500", height="500" )]   
    public class TestDecorator extends MovieClip
    {

        [Embed(source = 'bin-debug/animation.swf', mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        public static const EmbeddedAnimation : Class;

        private var _loader : Loader;
        private var _asset : ByteArrayAsset;
        private var _animation : MovieClip;

        public function TestDecorator()
        {
            super();

            // create asset
            _asset = new EmbeddedAnimation();

            // load bytes
            _loader = new Loader();
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoadCompleteHandler);
            _loader.loadBytes(_asset);
        }

        private function onLoadCompleteHandler(event : Event) : void
        {
            // remove listener
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoadCompleteHandler);

            // create asset as MovieClip
            _animation = MovieClip(_loader.content);

            // add a script that executes on the last frame
            _animation.addFrameScript(_animation.totalFrames - 1, lastFrameHandler)

            // add to displaylist
            addChild(_animation);
        }

        private function lastFrameHandler() : void
        {
            // add your fscommand here 
            // fscommand(*)

        }

        override public function play() : void
        {
            _animation.play();
        }

        override public function stop() : void
        {
            _animation.stop();
        }

        override public function get totalFrames() : int
        {
            return _animation.totalFrames;
        }

        override public function get currentFrame() : int
        {
            return _animation.currentFrame;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks like it may solve my issue. I'm not sure how to implement it however (Flash and AS are far from my strong point). I understand the code fine, are you able to explain the steps to get this to output the final file?

Comment: You need a compiler that can build the SWF file for you. I use Flash Builder, but there are a lot of other (even free ones) alternatives.

Comment: I have a Adobe Flash CS5.5, is it possible to do it with this?

Comment: Sure. Create an enoty FLA and set the document class in my example.

Comment: Thanks I think I am getting there :) I have got the code compiling, but it isn't loading the file to embed, looking through the source I don't understand where it loads the file. I can see where you declare which file to load, but not where it loads the file. Thanks so much for helping me out with this!

Comment: Ok, I noticed that the file is being embeded (the output file's size is matching the input) however the output file is completely white.. any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any compile errors? What is the target Flash Player version of the SWFs? Is the embedded file blank at the first frame? Try creating a SWF with some graphics in the first frame to ensure it loads correctly.

Comment: Do you get any compile errors? No.  
What is the target Flash Player version of the SWFs? Tried with 10.2 and 9.  
Is the embedded file blank at the first frame? No.  
Try creating a SWF with some graphics in the first frame to ensure it loads correctly. I have tried with multiple files created by different methods - they all appear white.

Comment: Hmm. I tried this myself using the Flash IDE. It seems you need the Flex SDK to embed the files like this.

Comment: Update: I have found the reason it is having issues is that the files I am loading are AS2. They need to load into an AVM1Movie type instead of a MovieClip object. However I have successfully figure out how to do this yet.